# fastest way to convert a file to list c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, binary-search

i have a file full of integers, sorted, i need to get the content of the file to a list.
the file looks something like this:

```
     1
     4
     45
     150
     245
     365
```

i know it's possible to read line by line and push_back, but the file count more than 500 000 line so is their a quick way to do this?

the goal is to see if an integer is in the file, so i need to convert to list and then do a binary_search, if you have a better idea, i'll be gratefull.

Comment: Depends if it's a one off search or something that you want to do multiple times.

Comment: Review the [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) container to take advantage of its log n search performance.  Then think about how to use each integer as a key.  The value can be the number of times that key appears in the file.

Comment: Are integers in your file already sorted ?

Comment: So, you do not actually want a std::list, but a std::vector, still better a std::unordered_list.

Comment: the file is sorted ; like shown in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search multiple times I suggest putting the file content into a hash table. This gives you O(1) lookup which is optimal.

Comment: I like this idea better than my suggestion on `std::map`

Comment: hi, i just want to see if an Int exist
for example if 45 exists in the file

Comment: Are the candidates known before? Are they hard-coded? In both cases read them in and immediately test them. Otherwise, `std::unordered_map` stays the proper container.

Comment: @Reda, if you only want to do it once you need no list either or any other data structure for that matter. Just operate on the file. This is the fastest. Think like this: if you do it once and you process all the file to put things into any data structure you already saw if the number was there that you want to look for, hence no need to data structure.

Comment: @Reda: yes, line by line if you search once.

Answer (score 2):

To read into list you can use `std::istreambuf_iterator`:

```
std::ifstream t( "file.txt");
std::list<int> l( ( std::istreambuf_iterator<int>( t)),
                     std::istreambuf_iterator<int>());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
  std::ifstream t { "file.txt", ios::ate };
  std::unordered_set s;
  s.reserve(t.tellg());
  t.seekg(0);
  s.insert(std::istream_iterator<int>(t), std::istream_iterator<int>());
// now you can use s.find(key) to see if something is in the set
}
```